# Ubuntu 12.10 torrent trackers down for you?

Tags: downloads, 12.10, bittorrent, tracker

are the Ubuntu 12.10 torrent trackers down for you?

http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce
http://ipv6.torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce

Their status for me is: `Not Working`

I am using `qbittorrent 3.0.6`

Comment: If you visit http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce, do you get `you sent me garbage - no info hash`?

Comment: did that and got that.

Comment: Your browser can connect, but not your torrent client. Weird.

Comment: Is this still happening? If so, it should be reported as a bug, though I'm not sure which Launchpad project corresponds to this. If someone can comment indicating which Launchpad project to report this as a bug against, we can close this question.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this. I am using Bittorrent on my Windows machine to get some Ubuntu releases as it has a fast connection, and I am not having issues. Since I do not have IPv6, the `http://ipv6.torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce` tracker cannot be resolved in DNS, but `http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce` is working. Looking at the numbers, quite a few peers and seeds are able to connect.

[image]

You can try adding a Web Seed(or HTTP seed) if your torrent client supports it, select the correct URL based on what you are downloading from http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/.

Try another torrent client, also.

Comment: well I decided to try it in transmission and it is working fine.